# Find the frequency of numbers using linkedlist

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

Find the frequency of numbers using linkedlist.

Getting SIGTSTP - time limit exceed error while running the below code. Can anyone help me where am I getting it wrong?

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new
        else:
            self.head = new

    def traverse(self):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.value)
            current = current.next            

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

ll = LinkedList()
for i in arr:
    e = Element(i)
    ll.append(e)

ll.traverse()

def frequency(a):
    current = a.head
    while current != None:
        count = 1
        while current.next != None:
            if current.value == current.next.value:
                current+=1
                if current.next.next != None:
                    current.next = current.next.next
                else:
                    current.next = None
        print(str(current.value)+" : " + str(count))
        current = current.next

frequency(ll)
```

Comment: Why are you adding to your item's value in your linked list?

Comment: @FarhoodET i am adding the element object to the linkedlist

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine except frequency. You will need to keep two references, one to the current element and the other will traverse the remainder of the list, starting from current. Does that give you something to go on?

Note too that your current implementation will modify the underlying linked list, while you can indeed do "skipping" with the pointers to prevent listing the same element multiple times, it is imo preferable to avoid modifying the underlying structure in this way.